# How convert an unsigned int to two unsigned shorts in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, byte

I originally had `2 WORD` (that's 4 bytes). I have stored them in an `unsigned int`. How can I split this such that I have 2 (left-most) bytes in one `unsigned short` variable and the other 2 bytes in another `unsigned short` variable?

I hope my question is clear, otherwise please tell me and I will add more details! :)

Example: I have this hexadecimal stored in unsigned int: `4f07aabb`

How can I turn this into two unsigned shorts so one of them holds `4f07` and the other holds `aabb`?

Comment: please post code in order to understand what you want

Comment: @Berto99 I haven't added any code to my question but an example. I hope it makes my question more clear (:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If* you are sure that `unsigned int` has at least 4 bytes on your target system (this is not guaranteed!), you can do:

```
unsigned short one = static_cast<unsigned short>(original >> (2 * 8));
unsigned short two = static_cast<unsigned short>(original % (1 << (2 * 8)));
```

This is only guaranteed to work if the original value indeed only contains a 4-byte value (possibly with padding zeroes in front). If you're not fond of bitshifting, you could also do

```
uint32_t original = 0x4f07aabb; // guarantee 32 bits
uint16_t parts[2];
std::memcpy(&parts[0], &original, sizeof(uint32_t));
unsigned short one = static_cast<unsigned short>(parts[0]);
unsigned short two = static_cast<unsigned short>(parts[1]);
```

This will yield the two values depending on the target system's endianness; on a litte-endian architecture, the results are reversed. You can check endianness with upcoming C++20's `std::endian::native`.

Comment: `unsigned short` always has at least 2 bytes. `unsigned int` does not necessarily have 4. And a byte is not necessarily 8 bits; it's at least 8, but in the olden days it was sometimes 9, and in modern times it is sometimes 32.

Comment: @PeteBecker A byte having 8 bits on the target system can be deduced from the question, I removed the remark about `unsigned short`.

Comment: You can write this code so it doesn’t rely on assumptions about the size of a byte by using `CHAR_BIT` instead of 8.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yes, however I try to not over-generalize code when the question clearly states that an assumption holds.

Comment: @flyx There is another problem with that approach: The order of bytes depends on the CPU architecture. On one system you might get `one == 0x4f07` and on another system `one == 0xaabb`. With shifts, you always get low order byte and high order byte regardless of CPU. On the other hand, sometimes you really do want the byte in memory order rather than order of of significance, although I think that case is rather rare.

Comment: @eerorika Thanks, added endianness discussion.